# Flutter app crashes very often after populating it with data and no errors are showed

Tags: flutter, crash

I have a flutter app that is complex enough and i have been developing it for a while.

the problem is after finishing up with the design code , i started implementing API's to receive actual data and populate the app with it. the app is now crashing quite a lot ( although a little less in release mode).

I am thinking it might be because the android device runs out of memory because of all the complex widgets I display in the app.

I have build all of my widgets Stateful I don't know if that could be a related factor (I am a beginner with flutter programming).

Please I have spent a lot of time in developing this app and it's my first enterprise level flutter app.

I haven't had experience with flutter before and I knew this kind of problems would arise and have no solution I would have gone with Java and Swift to develop the app.

Any help is appreciated guys. 
Tanks.

Comment: Have you tried it in real devices?

Comment: Yes. I am actually running it on a real android device and this problem occurs.

Comment: oops. I prefer you to raise this as an issue at flutter on github.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I'll try that too. Do you think Stateless Vs Statful could be the cause for all these crashes ?

Comment: Sorry I don't know much about it.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out using Stateful widgets through out the app takes up too much memory of the device and thus causing the crashes.

I reached out to the Flutter team on GitHub as suggested by Aneesh (Thank you Aneesh), and they recommend reading this for a better understanding of the Stateful Vs Stateless widget, here is the link :

> https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/interactive